# Calling function with keyword arguments chosen from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I want to call functions with keyword arguments from a dictionary. I figured out how to do it for one function at a time with **kwargs. But I have a dictionary containing keyword arguments for multiple functions. Is that possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

yummy_stuff = {"strawberries" : "these red small thingies",
               "apples": "this round hand-sized fruit",
               "oranges": "the yellow ball thing with the skin",
               "waffles": "these flat buttery discs",
               "icecream": "the cold cone stuff",
               "chocolate": "the brown melty stuff that comes in bars"}

def return_fruit(strawberries, apples, oranges):
    return "You know, {0}, {1} and {2} are yummy!".format(strawberries, apples, oranges)

def return_dessert(waffles, icecream, chocolate):
    return "But {0}, {1} and {2} are nice as well!".format(waffles, icecream, chocolate)

print return_fruit(**yummy_stuff)

-> TypeError: return_fruit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chocolate'
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Short answer: Not easily.

Comment: Why cant't you use return_fruit(**kwargs)  and get kwargs['organges'] ?